# Are there alternatives to ibtool for parsing NIB files?

Tags: macos, internationalization, nib

As part of an i18n project, I need to extract strings from a NIB file programmatically.  This can be done quite easily with ibtool, of course.  But this is a cross-platform product, of which the NIB is only part.  It would be nice if we didn't have to lock string extraction to a particular machine, or have to kludge together catalog-merge scripts.

So I realize it's a long shot, since the demand for this is probably quite low, but are there any open-source alternatives to ibtool?  Is there any documentation on the NIB format reliable enough to write a parser from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XIBs, then they are simple XML files. Just look for `string` elements that have the key `NSContents`. If you're familiar with XML parsing, it shouldn't take long to reverse engineer `--export-strings-file` in almost any language.

If you can't move to XIBs, you can read the `keyedobjects.nib`, which is a binary plist. One portable reader is the Perl implementation [plutil.pl](http://scw.us/iPhone/plutil/). You can also look at Apple's open source code to handle them in [CFBinaryPlist.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c). If you need to go this way, look at [OpenCFLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencflite/). Reading and writing Plists is a key reason people use the portable Core Foundation.

Comment: I didn't know about XIBs; exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!